# Passing file to shell script multiple times

Tags: bash, sh

I have a shell script where I pass a txt file to the script as follows:

```
./run.sh < list.txt
```

Within the script, I am doing a "`while read LIST do ... end`"

It all works well, and the script executes using the list.

However, now I want to have a second `while read LIST do ... end` in the same shell script.  I want it to read again from the original list I'm passing it on execution, but it doesn't work.  It reads the list.txt file for the first loop, but not the second.

What do I do to make the script read list.txt each time I'm asking for it?

Comment: Why do you need to read the file twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't read stdin twice. Try passing list.txt on the command-line rather than redirecting it.

```
./run.sh list.txt
```

Then in your script:

```
while read LINE; do
    ...
done < "$1"

while read LINE; do
    ...
done < "$1"
```

Alternatively, save the contents of stdin off the first time you read through it. For instance:

```
# First loop, save stdin in an array.
LINES=()

while read LINE; do
    LINES+=("$LINE")
    ...
done

# Second loop, iterate over the array.
for LINE in "${LINES[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Comment: bash's [`mapfile`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile) would be useful in your 2nd scenario

Comment: Dumb question but...in my question I was using `while read LIST; do`, but you changed it to `LINE`, is this important?  Or in your first example is the important parts passing list.txt on the command line and adding < "$1" after done for each loop?

Comment: @user1644609 The variable name isn't important. I just changed it to be a bit more descriptive, i.e. each iteration it holds a single line from the input file. The important part is the `< "$1"`.

Comment: @glennjackman Spiffy! I just learned something new.

Comment: @JohnKugelman - when I run my revised script (by doing `./run_rev.sh list.txt` - I get an error on each line with the `done < "$1"` saying `list.txt No such file or directory`.  list.txt, and run_rev.sh are in the same directory (and it is from within that directory that I'm executing the script).  Any idea of what I've done wrong?

Comment: same error occurs when I use the complete path (./run_rev.sh /full/path/to/list.txt)

Comment: I kept getting the error mentioned above when doing your first method, however the second method works as I hoped.  Is there a more efficient way using mapfile that I should use?

Comment: @user1644609 That's really strange. Maybe post that as a separate question, why the `$1` method says no such file? That would be my preferred solution, if you could get it working.